# Set max rows to return using sqlplus

Tags: sql, database, oracle, command-line, sqlplus

I know I can add: `where rownum <= 100` to each query but is there any global SET command in sqlplus that can limit the number of results returned by a query?

ie `SET MAX_ROWS_TO_RETURN 100` so that it applies to all queries?

The reason is because I have a bunch of sql files that I run using `@name.sql` and I don't want to have to alter each sql file individually.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such option.

At least nothing is documented in the manual:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve001.htm